# Failed to deserialize Confluent Avro record using Flink-SQL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, confluent-schema-registry, flink-sql

Cannot consume the Confluent Kafka data using Flink-sql.

Fink version：1.12-csadh1.3.0.0
Cluster：Cloudera（CDP）
Kafka：Confluent Kafka

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE consumer_session_created (
***
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = '***', 
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset', 
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '***:9092', 
  'properties.group.id' = '***', 
  'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_SSL', 
  'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'PLAIN', 
  'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="***" password="***"', 
  'properties.avro-confluent.basic-auth.credentials-source' = '***', 
  'properties.avro-confluent.basic-auth.user-info' = '***', 
  'value.format' = 'avro-confluent', 
  'value.fields-include' = 'EXCEPT_KEY', 
  'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = 'https://***', 
  'value.avro-confluent.schema-registry.subject' = '***'
)
```

Error Msg:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize Avro record.
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:101)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:44)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.table.DynamicKafkaDeserializationSchema.deserialize(DynamicKafkaDeserializationSchema.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.partitionConsumerRecordsHandler(KafkaFetcher.java:179)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:142)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:826)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:241)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find schema with id 79 in registry
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.registry.confluent.ConfluentSchemaRegistryCoder.readSchema(ConfluentSchemaRegistryCoder.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.RegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.deserialize(RegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:98)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Unauthorized; error code: 401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:292)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:352)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:660)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:642)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:217)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:291)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaById(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:276)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient.getById(SchemaRegistryClient.java:64)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.registry.confluent.ConfluentSchemaRegistryCoder.readSchema(ConfluentSchemaRegistryCoder.java:74)
    ... 11 more
```

I thought I used the parameters `avro-confluent.basic-auth.*` in the wrong way, according to the [flink Doc here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/formats/avro-confluent.html#avro-confluent-basic-auth-credentials-source). So I removed the prefix `properties.`:

```
WITH (
  'connector',
  *** 
  'avro-confluent.basic-auth.credentials-source' = '***', 
  'avro-confluent.basic-auth.user-info' = '***', 
  ***
)
```

However, another exception raised:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unsupported options found for connector 'kafka'.
Unsupported options:
avro-confluent.basic-auth.credentials-source 
avro-confluent.basic-auth.user-info
```

Tips:
we can consume/de-ser the kafka data correctly using DataStream API with same parameters, and this topic has been used for a long time by others'.

Comment: This is a known bug for some specific flink version. Failed to pass an ssl configuration to the Confluent schema registry format. This issue has been fixed in version  1.14.0, 1.12.5, 1.13.2. Jira ticket is here[https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-21229].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Flink packed into Cloudera distributive, but in simple (original) Flink I connect to Kafka using SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE my_flink_table (
     event_date AS TO_TIMESTAMP(eventtime_string_field, 'yyyyMMddHHmmssX') 
    ,field1
    ,field2
    ...
    ,WATERMARK FOR event_date AS event_date - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic' = 'my_events_topic',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
    'format' = 'avro-confluent',
    'avro-confluent.schema-registry.url' = 'http://my_confluent_schma_reg_host:8081/',
    'properties.group.id' = 'flink-test-001',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka_host01:9092'
);
```